# Finding expected total number of die rolls

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, dice

**Question**

Ann and Bob take turns to roll a fair six-sided die. The game ends after a six or three consecutive fives come up, with the winner being the last person who threw the die. Ann will go first.

$(a)\quad$ Find the probability that Ann will win.

$(b)\quad$ Find the expected total number of rolls.

**My working**

Let $(A, 0)$ denote the state in which it is $A$'s turn and the prior toss was not a $5$ or a $6$, $(A, 5)$ the state in which it is $A$'s turn and the prior toss was a $5$ and $(A, 55)$ the state in which it is $A$'s turn and the prior two tosses were a $5$. The states for $B$ are defined similarly and note also that $(A, 0)$ is the starting state.

Now, for any state $S$, let $P(S)$ denote the probability that $A$ will eventually win, given that we are now in state $S$ and we have the following relationships:

$$\begin{aligned}
P(A, 0) & = \frac 1 6 + \frac 1 6 P(B, 5) + \frac 4 6 P(B, 0)
\\[5 mm] P(A, 5) & = \frac 1 6 + \frac 1 6 P(B, 55) + \frac 4 6 P(B, 0)
\\[5 mm] P(A, 55) & = \frac 2 6 + \frac 4 6 P(B, 0)
\\[5 mm] P(B, 0) & = \frac 1 6 P(A, 5) + \frac 4 6 P(A, 0)
\\[5 mm] P(B, 5) & = \frac 1 6 P(A, 55) + \frac 4 6 P(A, 0)
\\[5 mm] P(B, 55) & = \frac 4 6 P(A, 0)
\end{aligned}$$

The system of linear equations above can be easily solved to give $P(A, 0) = \frac {93} {170}$, which is the correct answer for $(a)$.

However, I am not sure how to approach $(b)$, whose answer is $\frac {129} {22}$. Any intuitive suggestions will be greatly appreciated :)

---

**Edit**

Following some hints Joe posted in an answer, I managed to solve $(b)$ :)

Let $X$ be the number of dice rolls it takes for the game to stop, $A$ be the event that a $5$ is first rolled, $B$ the event that a $6$ is first rolled and $C$ the event that neither a $5$ nor a $6$ is first rolled.

By the law of iterated expectation, we have

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(X) & = \mathbb{E}(X \mid A) \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{E}(X \mid B) \mathbb{P}(B) + \mathbb{E}(X \mid C) \mathbb{P}(C)
\\[5 mm] & = (1)\left(\frac 1 6\right) + \mathbb{E}(X \mid B) \mathbb{P}(B) + [\mathbb{E}(X) + 1]\left(\frac 4 6\right)
\end{aligned}$$

To find $\mathbb{E}(X \mid B) \mathbb{P}(B)$, I chose to consider different cases.

1. The game ends with three $5$s or two $5$s and a $6$, each case happening with probability $\left(\frac 1 6\right)^3$ and taking three turns to end.
2. The game ends with one $5$ and one $6$, which happens with probability $\left(\frac 1 6\right)^2$ and takes two turns to end.

We must also not forget the cases where the game does not end (immediately).

3. Two $5$s are thrown, followed by neither a $5$ nor a $6$, which happens with probability $\left(\frac 1 6\right)^2\left(\frac 4 6\right)$ and takes $\mathbb{E}(X + 3)$ turns to end.
4. One $5$ is thrown, followed by neither a $5$ nor a $6$, which happens with probability $\left(\frac 1 6\right)\left(\frac 4 6\right)$ and takes $\mathbb{E}(X + 2)$ turns to end.

These four cases, when added up, will give

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(X \mid B) \mathbb{P}(B) & = \left(\frac 1 6\right)^3(3)(2) + \left(\frac 1 6\right)^2(2) + \left(\frac 1 6\right)^2\left(\frac 4 6\right)[\mathbb{E}(X + 3)] + \left(\frac 1 6\right)\left(\frac 4 6\right)[\mathbb{E}(X + 2)]
\\[5 mm] & = \frac 1 {12} + \frac 1 {54} \mathbb{E}(X + 3) + \frac 1 9 \mathbb{E}(X + 2)
\end{aligned}$$

Thus,

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(X) & = (1)\left(\frac 1 6\right) + \mathbb{E}(X \mid B) \mathbb{P}(B) + [\mathbb{E}(X) + 1]\left(\frac 4 6\right)
\\[5 mm] & = \frac 1 6 + \frac 1 {12} + \frac 1 {54} \mathbb{E}(X + 3) + \frac 1 9 \mathbb{E}(X + 2) + \frac 4 6 \mathbb{E}(X + 1)
\\[5 mm] & = \frac 1 4 + \frac 1 {54} \mathbb{E}(X + 3) + \frac 1 9 \mathbb{E}(X + 2) + \frac 4 6 \mathbb{E}(X + 1)
\\[5 mm] & = \frac {43} {36} + \frac {43} {54} \mathbb{E}(X)
\\[5 mm] \implies \mathbb{E}(X) & = \frac {129} {22}
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of dice rolls that it takes for the game to stop. When we first roll the die, there are essentially $3$ options that can come up:

1. A $6$ comes up. Call this event "$A$".
2. A $5$ comes up. Call this event "$B$".
3. Neither a $5$ nor a $6$ comes up. Call this event "$C$".

The law of iterated expectation states that
$$
\mathbb{E}(X)=\mathbb{E}(X\mid A)\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{E}(X\mid B)\mathbb{P}(B)+\mathbb{E}(X\mid C)\mathbb{P}(C)
$$
It is trivial to compute the probabilities of $A$, $B$, and $C$ occurring.

If event $A$ occurs, then the game stops and $X=1$. Hence, $\mathbb{E}(X\mid A)=1$. If event $C$ occurs, then you have essentially wasted a turn. It will take another $\mathbb{E}(X)$ rolls on average for the game to stop. Hence, the overall number of expected spins $\mathbb{E}(X\mid C)=\mathbb{E}(X)+1$.

Calculating $\mathbb{E}(X|B)$ is harder. Given that you have rolled a $5$, you must again consider the possibilities that

- A $6$ comes up.
- A $5$ comes up.
- Neither a $5$ nor a $6$ comes up.

Can you work things out from here?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I have worked on your hints and worked it all out under an edit in my post :)

Comment: @EthanMark: No worries! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

If $x$ is the expected number of rolls, $y$ is the expected number of rolls from $S(5)$ and $z$ is the expected number of rolls from $S(55)$, then we have

$\left
\{\begin{array}
{l}x = 1 + \dfrac{1}{6} \cdot y + \dfrac{4}{6} \cdot x \\ y = 1 + \dfrac{4}{6} \cdot x + \dfrac{1}{6} \cdot z \\
z = 1 + \dfrac{4}{6} \cdot x
\end{array}
\right.$

Solving, $x = \dfrac{129}{22}$

Comment: Oh, what a succinct answer! Thank you so much for this as well, although I am not able to accept it since I have already accepted an earlier one! Very nice indeed :)

Comment: @MathLover: Did you work out what $x$ is in the following way? $$x = \frac{1}{6} \cdot 1 + \dfrac{1}{6} \cdot(y+1) + \dfrac{4}{6} \cdot (x+1) \, ,$$because there is a $1/6$ chance of it taking $1$ time (if you roll a $6$), a $1/6$ chance of rolling a $5$, and a $4/6$ chance of you wasting a roll, and so it takes $x+1$ rolls on average. Simplifying this, we get what you wrote. Is that how you thought about the problem?

Comment: @EthanMark: Math Lover's answer certainly is more succinct than mine, and so if you prefer it then feel free to accept his answer instead.

Comment: @Joe you can write it as $x = \dfrac{1}{6} \cdot 1 + \dfrac{1}{6} \cdot (y + 1) + \dfrac{4}{6} \cdot (x+1)$. It is the same thing. The way I am doing it this roll is $1$ and then additional rolls based on different probabilities.

Comment: @MathLover: I understand now. Thank you! Your answer is more elegant than mine, so $+1$ from me.

Comment: @Joe that's alright. your answer is nice too. I do not think OP should change it.

Comment: @MathLover: No worries! It is a very nice problem and I am glad we both found solutions to it.

Comment: @MathLover: (+1) I presume that $z$ is appearing in the equations only because it is a 2-person game ?

Comment: @trueblueanil thank you. No it would not matter even if it was one person. The way the question is, it doesn't distinguish between which player gets the favorable outcomes. All we are finding is the expected number of rolls to get either a six or $3$ consecutive five's.

Comment: @MathLover: Oh, sorry, I didn't read the question, I thought two $5's$ are enough. Very elegant answer